# Python: most effective way of filtering a list

Tags: python, filter

I hope I'm not duplicating here :-)

I'm wondering what's the most effective way of filtering a python list.
The task I have in hand is to find out list elements that are not appearing in some other list.

My fist list is a list of objects (without unnecessary details):

```
Class A:
    def __init__(self,item1, item2):
        self.item1 = item1
        self.item2 = item2
```

later on, in my script I'm parsing a input text file and populating a `list1` with real data (both `item1` and `item2` fields are strings)

there's also a second list, `list2` containing just a list of strings coresponding to `item1`. What I'm interested in, are the elements in `list1` where `item1` is not in the `list2`.

 *(`list1` contains roughly 3000 elements, `list2` is bigger - circa 60000 elements. )*

my fist attempt is quite obvious:

```
notMatched = list(itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x.item1 not in list2), list1))
```

now, it works as expected, giving me exactly what I want, but I'm still wondering if it's the best solution I could came with.
Any idea anyone?

Thanks

Comment: Your solution would benefit from converting `list2` to a `set`, but you will probably find that the list comprehension in Daren's answer is faster (and easier to read)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `list2` a set. This will improve the performance of the lookup `not in list2`.

You can probably get away with this:

```
set2 = set(list2)
not_matched = [a for a in list1 if not a.item1 in set2]
```

Comment: Would it be ok to convert both lists to `set` when getting the `not_matched`? e.g `not_matched = set(list1) ^ set(list2)` .. Are there performance issues here?

Comment: This will not work, since `list1` and `list2` are of different types. I'm not sure if you could solve that by writing an `A.__cmp__`. Also, you lose the ordering - assuming you want to keep it. As for performance issues: Creating a `set` from a sequence *has* to be O(n) at least. Intersecting two `set`s is probably at least O(n) too, so, no, that won't ever be faster. Unless you have the sets handy already...